# Yesod: Passing the current user to a form

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I've looked for this, but the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714297/how-get-the-user-id-from-the-session-at-yesod-haskell-project) ends up on a list containing the value. I'm wondering if there isn't another, more straightforward way to do what I need.

I have a form:

```
formReview :: UserId -> Form Review
formReview uid = renderDivs $ Review <$>
              areq textField "Text" Nothing <*>
              areq intField "Rating" Nothing <*>
              areq (selectField films) "Film" Nothing <*>
              pure uid
```

as you can see I'm trying to pass an user ID to the form, because these are the fields for Review:

```
Review
    text Text
    rating Int
    film FilmId
    author UserId
```

it requires the ID of the author.
The way I'm trying to do this is by doing the following on postReviewsR:

```
postReviewsR :: Handler Html
postReviewsR = do
                uid <- lookupSession "_ID"
                case uid of
                  Nothing -> do
                     defaultLayout [whamlet| <h1> User isn't logged in.|]
                  Just uid -> 
                     ((result, _), _) <- runFormPost $ formReview uid
                     case result of
                        FormSuccess review -> do
                            runDB $ insert review
                            defaultLayout [whamlet|
                                <h1> Review posted. 
                            |]
                        _ -> redirect ReviewsR
```

it has to be a Maybe because in theory you could try to post something without being logged in, so uid could be empty. If I try to go straight to `((result, _), _) <- runFormPost $ formReview uid` it says there's a `Maybe Text`.

Now my problem is similar the other post, it's this error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘Key User’
  Expected type: UserId
    Actual type: Text
• In the first argument of ‘formReview’, namely ‘uid’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘formReview uid’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    ((result, _), _) <- runFormPost $ formReview uid
```

and the suggestion in the linked post is to use `keyToValues :: Key record -> [PersistValue]` to turn the Key, which apparently is just Text, into what I need, the UserId. 
It seems too clunky to me that I would need to do all this, then use `head` on that list to get the value within, all to get the ID into the form. There has to be another, more correct way, right? What am I missing here? How do I get the ID of the user who's making the Review in there?

EDIT: I should point out that I'm not using Yesod.Auth so I can't use its functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using a SQL backend, check out the [`persistent` SQL documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.7.0/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html). You'll find the `toSqlKey :: ToBackendKey SqlBackend record => Int64 -> Key record` function. Basically, you'll need to parse your `Text` to `Int64` and get a key using `toSqlKey`. You should *probably* also check if the key you're getting is actually valid.

(You've apparently misread the error, your `uid` is just a `Text` value, but you need a `UserID` which is a `Key User`).

Comment: I'm using postgresql, I'll look for a similar function if it has one.

Comment: If you're using postgresql you're using a SQL backend. This is defined in `Persistent.SQL`, which you're using if you're using postgresql with `persistent`.